# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Attributes>>'

Tags: flutter, api

am trying to fetch api to my app but there is that error

```
Future<List<Attributes>> getPosts() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(get_categ));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return (jsonResponse);
    } else {
      throw Exception('there is an error');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getPosts().then((value) => print(value));
    super.initState();
  }
```

i alos try this code and many code i have try to fix this problem

```
Future<List<Attributes>> getPosts() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(get_categ));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return (jsonResponse as List).map((e) => Attributes.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('there is an error');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getPosts().then((value) => print(value));
    super.initState();
  }
```

i build a model class that was is nested json that is my model class

```
class Attributes {
  Attributes({
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
  });

  final String? name;
  final Image? image;

  factory Attributes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Attributes(
      name: json["name"],
      image: json["image"] == null ? null : Image.fromJson(json["image"]),
    );
  }
```

I try many codes but all of them was old maybe there is an change on syntext on flutter

Answer (score 0):

Is your object a List of objects or a single object ? As you name your method and the return object, it same you are waiting for a list of atrributes objects.

```
var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body); 
List<Attributes> = jsonResponse.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>().map<Attributes>((x) => Attributes.fromJson(x)).toList();
```

I think this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I have this error //// NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.   //// I think I have try this code befor